# Getting 403:Forbidden posting to my timeline

Tags: android, google-mirror-api

I have enabled mirror API for my project in developer console. I authorized mirror API and generated an access token in the OAuth playground. Building a request in playground or sending it manually I always get 403 error. Can anyone help?

wget --header="Authorization: Bearer access-token" --header="Content-Type: application/json" --post-data="{ \"text\": \"Hello world\" }" https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline
--2014-02-07 00:35:00--  https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline
Resolving www.googleapis.com (www.googleapis.com)... 74.125.129.95, 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::5f
Connecting to www.googleapis.com (www.googleapis.com)|74.125.129.95|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-02-07 00:35:00 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Building a request in playground**

On [Glass Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground) site there is a red button named **Show Playground usage information** at the bottom.

If you click that button you'll see the **To give the Playground access to a timeline** information.

To give the Playground access to a timeline:

1. Create a [Google APIs project client ID](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:access).
2. Add https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com to the list of
   authorized JavaScript origins for the client ID
   [image]
3. Copy your client ID to the Playground and start interacting with
   your timeline.
   [image]

**2) Building a request programmatically**

If you have `403: Forbidden` error while sending `TimelineItem`s programmatically, that's probably because you are not using the correct values of your **clientId** and **clientSecret**.

**Edit:** Three items are copied from [Glass Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground) site(under the red button).